# Scheduled task pass information to remote computer

Tags: powershell

I am writing a module for Windows Updates in PowerShell (let's not go into the "there's already a few that do that" argument) and as discussed quite a few times, the Windows Update COM object cannot be called remotely.

So, the way around it is to create a scheduled task on the remote computer which calls invokes the functions in the module. However, one of the things that's always been left out in modules that do this, is the status reporting back to the invoking computer.

The invoking computer creates the scheduled task and then has no idea of what is going on afterwards. How many updates the remote computer has to install, how many succeeded, how many failed, etc.

So, what I'm after is the best way of passing this information from the remote computer back to the invoking computer.

I've thought of two ways so far:

- Named pipes - this works great in theory and this is exactly what they were designed for. However, I'm not sure they're the best possible solution here, as using them would mean that the remote computer needs to be able to resolve the invoking computer (DNS), can connect to the remote computer (no firewall in between), etc. This is supposed to be something that 'just works' out of the box, not something that requires a lot of setup and reading manuals before being able to use it.
- Event viewer - While event viewer was never meant as a means for passing live status information, in this particular case it might actually work better. Connectivity from the invoking computer to the remote computer is already guaranteed, as the invoking computer was able to create the scheduled task on the invoking computer. The remote computer is not sending anything, so it doesn't need to be able to resolve or have connectivity to the invoking computer.

I'm discounting things like writing to a log file as they are poorer variations of using the event viewer.

I'd like to hear some advice on which method would be better for this (not limited to the ones above, if you can think of something better please do chip in) and why.

Comment: Have you already looked at WSUS? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157

Comment: That answer is so off context I don't even know what to say. You want me to use WSUS to pass information from a remote computer to the invoking computer where the remote computer is running a scheduled task? Because that's the question really.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. You appear to be trying to manage updates, so I thought I would offer an alternative solution to the intent you presented here. However, if the ONLY thing you want is RPC, then you ask a simpler question.

Comment: The reason why I mentioned updates was just to give it some context. The question itself is how to pass information from a remote computer running a scheduled task (which is a PowerShell script) to another computer? There are no sessions here since it's a scheduled task that called the script on the remote computer.

Comment: For just logging, check out NLog. It has a simpler api, and supports an eventlog target. It would also allow users of said module to configure the endpoint for logging themselves, should they want to use SQL, Redis, Splunk, etc...

Comment: While using NLog itself is not a bad idea per say, it only becomes worthwhile if you use all of its features (including ability to log to SQL, Redis, Splunk, etc). And that poses other issues when running on the remote machine: name resolution, connectivity, permissions, etc. It is a good idea to run on the invoking machine, but not for the remote machine, so the question still remains I'm afraid, which is how to pass the info from the remote machine to the invoking machine.